# Accessing data in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

on my homepage I have a forEach loop which shows promotions from different businesses under the Business model.  In my index.js controller I have promotions defined like this (the shuffle is a random sort, but not relevant here):

```
let promotions = [];
businesses.forEach(business => {
    promotions = promotions.concat(business.promotions);
});
shuffleArray(promotions);
```

On my homepage, the promotions are displayed like this:

```
<div class="gold">
  <% promotions.forEach(function(promotion) { %>
    <img class='lazy business-advert-image' data-src="<%- cloudinary.url(promotion.public_id, {width: 450, height: 300, crop: 'pad', quality: 'auto', fetch_format: 'auto', flags: 'lossy'}) %>" alt="Business Advertising Promotion">
  <% }); %>
</div>
```

This is working absolutely fine, though in addition to this, I am also trying to overlay the name of the business that the promotion comes from (it is a one-to-many relationship, i.e. one business might have 5 different promotions).  However, I am struggling with how to access other fields from the Business model. I have tried:

```
promotion.business.name
business.name
```

Both of these are giving a 'business is not defined' error; and also:

```
business.promotion.name
```

which gives an undefined error.

Can anyone please advise how I can access the name (or other fields in the Business model)?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would do the heavy lifting in your controller and avoid using a nested loop in the view layer.

So the controller method would have:

```
let promotions = [];
businesses.forEach(business => {
    let businessPromotions = business.promotions.map(promotion => {
        promotion.businessName = business.name;
        return promotion;
    })
  promotions = promotions.concat(businessPromotions);
});
```

then in the view you can access the business name via `<%= promotion.businessName %>` (within the promotions forEach loop)

Comment: Thanks @nax3t, just what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to send business name from your server also. You are only  promotions in your array right now.
    promotions = promotions.concat(business.promotions);
Above line adding data into array like this

```
array=[
promotionArray1[5],
promotionArray2[5]
]
```

this structure do not have business name.It have only promotions.So you need to change it like this
this should be like this

```
promotions = promotions.concat(business);
```

which mean this time array would be like this

```
array=[
business1.promotionArray1[5],
business2.promotionArray2[5]
]
```

now in ejs, you need to put nested loop to get access all data.

```
<div class="gold">
<% promotions.forEach(function(business) { %>
<% business.forEach(function(promotion1) { %>
 put your html here.
 business.name
 promotion1.name
 <% }); %>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Could you please clarify however what you mean by promotion1 and promotion2?  As the issue is not with accessing multiple promotions, but rather accessing the business name for the currently displayed promotion.  Am I misunderstanding something here?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, though when I use that code I'm getting business.forEach is not a function